# php image swap. swap files instead

Tags: php

I want to be able to swap files instead of images. I've changed some of the code myself but wasn't very successful. What do I need to change to make it work? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

$url = "http://site.com/days";
$monImage = "$url"."monday.jpg";
$tueImage = "$url"."tuesday.jpg";
$wedImage = "$url"."wednesday.jpg";
$thurImage = "$url"."thursday.jpg";
$friImage = "$url"."friday.jpg";
$weekendImage = "$url"."weekend.jpg";
$d = date("D");

switch ($d)
{
case Mon:
echo "<img src=$monImage>\n";
break;
case Tue:
echo "<img src=$tueImage>\n";
break;
case Wed:
echo "<img src=$wedImage>\n";
break;
case Thu:
echo "<img src=$thurImage>\n";
break;
case Fri:
echo "<img src=$friImage>\n";
break;
default:
echo "<img src=$weekendImage>\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Your question needs more details. Where do you get the files from?

Comment: You need quotes around your cases, firstly. 'Mon', etc.

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<img src="http://site.com/days' . strtolower( date('l') ) . '.jpg" />';`

Comment: Xeon, there's a folder on my site labeled "days". The files that i want to use would be called from that folder. I would prefer that the code above use tables from mysql but wasn't sure if this is possible.

Comment: What i'm really looking to do is have a class schedule on my site. Example: Monday: 8am - Sketching class • 9am - aerobics. Tuesday: 9am - spinning class, etc

I only want to show monday's actives on monday. Then tuesday's activities on tuesday. The code above would swap out the days accordingly.